# Как сравнить ответ пользователя с текстом в python библиотеке fuzzywuzzy?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть телеграмм бот:
import telebot
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import random
import time

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_start(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Привет, я граммбот, я буду давать тебе слова а ты должен      будешь их правильно записать!Для этого введи команду test')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def send_help(message):
nt = random.randint(1, 4)

if nt == 1:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'к.л.сок, доро.ка')
    time.sleep(10)
    a1 = fuzz.WRatio(message.text, 'колосок, дорожка')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, a1)
elif nt == 2:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'поз.ний, ро.ь')
    time.sleep(10)
    a2 = fuzz.WRatio(message.text, 'поздний, рожь')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, a2)
elif nt == 3:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ра.будить, предпол.гать')
    time.sleep(10)
    a3 = fuzz.WRatio(message.text, 'разбудить, предполагать')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, a3)
else:
    time.sleep(10)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ошибка")






bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Но код не работает, при вводе пользователем правильных слов, которые 100% совпадают с текстом, бот выдает 0.Я думаю, бот не может сравнивать текст с ответом пользователя, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш message.text = /test, после нажатия fuzz.WRatio('/test', 'колосок, дорожка') = 0. Вам нужно изменить логику вашего бота и прикрутить состояния, переходите с telebot на aiogram, там это сделать проще

Comment: Всмысле изменить логику?